# Training Model for Each Individual in AzureML

Tags: multi-tenant, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to train an ANN model for each individual, in azure ml. For example, there is an application which wants to learn the behavior of each individual separately. How is this possible in azure-ml? Any suggestion?

As I know, I can create a model and train it with some data, but I don't know how can I train it specifically for each user. I should mention that I am seeking for a scalable idea which is applicable for a real situation (might be for 100 thousands users).

Comment: What kind of prediction you going to do after the behavioral understanding of each user?

Comment: @HarithaThilakarathne ANN model.

Comment: Not that... what is the purpose of doing the prediction?

Comment: @HarithaThilakarathne Personalize the behavior of the bot for each individual user.

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend the [Create many Machine Learning models and web service endpoints from one experiment using PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-create-models-and-endpoints-with-powershell) article on this topic. It uses [Azure ML PowerShell](https://github.com/hning86/azuremlps) to automate creation of web services that have identical structure but user-specific trained models. Your application would need to keep track of the correspondence between web service and user.

Comment: It is not applicable! Do you mean, If I have 200 thousands users, I should create 200 thousands web service endpoints! is it a rational movement?! How?

Comment: Sorry this answer was not useful to you. Maybe you could add the scale to your question, since it's relevant to the choice of approach.